# Dye-ing to know where to acquire dye

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find specific dye colors?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67321/where-can-i-find-specific-dye-colors)

Bad puns aside (of which the title is a very bad one), whereabouts do you acquire dye from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many merchants will sell dyes.  I know that as soon as you reach Act 2, there is a merchant who has a variety of dyes for sale, but I found some merchants in Act 1 who also sold them.

Of course, if you have the Collector's edition, you should also have access to the special dyes that were part of that package.