# Where can I find specific dye colors?

Tags: diablo-iii

So far all of Act I merchants have sold Green, Brown, or White dyes, while all of Act II merchants have sold Green, Brown, White, or Blue dyes. The number of different colors for sale, and which colors are available seems to vary for each merchant at any given time.

So I'm thinking that specific merchants (or perhaps all merchants in a specific Act or Difficulty) only sell specific dye colors (correct me if I'm wrong here in a comment, and I'll update)

Can someone provide me with a list of where I can find each color of Dye?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dye-ing to know where to acquire dye](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66623/dye-ing-to-know-where-to-acquire-dye)

Comment: I know that when I got to the alchemist, he was offering Blue as one of the dyes. This doesn't address whether he rotates among 4 colors instead of 3, or he can have any of them; I don't really know much about dyes. Posting as it may be a useful data point if others have also got him to stock other colored dyes.

Comment: @FAE Thanks, I did look at that question but I would like to know where I can find specific dyes, not dyes in general. I will update my question.

Comment: @FAE: Think the OP is asking _where_ to buy specific dyes which is not covered by that question (nor the one linked from there).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many different dyes exist and are they permanent?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66487/how-many-different-dyes-exist-and-are-they-permanent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dyes seem to be found per difficulty level, and are random within the the game as to what colors you find with what merchants

Each difficulty level will have new dye colors in addition to the dyes from the difficulty levels below it

**Normal**: Aquatic (Light Blue), Spring (Light Green), Tanner's (Brown), Winter (Light Grey)

**Nightmare**: Cardinal (Red), Royal (Light Purple), Desert, Ranger (Green), Autumn (Orange)

**Hell**: Lovely (Light Pink), Elegant (Dark Pink), Marine (Blue), Summer

**Inferno**: Gold, Inferno (Red), Abyssal (Black), Purity (White), Forrester (Green)

**Edit**

The only exception seems to be the Act I dye merchant in New Tristan. He doesn't seem to live by the same rules than the other Dye merchants do, although I haven't quite figured out what his rules are.

**Normal**: Green, Brown, and Light Grey only

**Nightmare**: Wasn't paying attention

**Hell**: Only had Normal + Nightmare colors until either Act II, or a specific point in Act I. I can't remember which, but do remember being disappointed that he didn't have new colors, and know I spent quite a bit of time in Act I and checked his colors many times

**Inferno**: Had two new colors the first time I saw him, so perhaps I just had bad luck in Hell?

Comment: FYI, there is also a GOLD dye. I've only seen it in the AH and it isn't cheap!

Comment: There's a gold dye in Inferno difficulty

Comment: NO BLACK DYE!?!?

Comment: @Codemonkey There is a black dye per [blizzard's website](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dye/), however I haven't found it yet so it probably shows up in Inferno or later in Nightmare

Comment: Yeah check [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66491/4536)

Comment: black is called abysmal i think found in inferno im pretty sure

Comment: The Wandering Tinker in the Fields of Misery (Tinkers Hovel) also sells the Lovely Dye.

Answer (score 5):

All dyes are available at [Myriam](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Myriam_Jahzia) npc.

> Dyes functionality was added directly to her interface in patch 2.4.3, removing dyes from vendors. Gold prices for dyes remained unchanged.