# When do Dye Merchants change their inventory?

Tags: diablo-iii

So, as per [Where can I find specific dye colors?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67321/where-can-i-find-specific-dye-colors) it seems that dye colors are somewhat random as to where you find them. In Act II, I was able to buy acquatic dye and spring dye from the merchant to the right of the entrance to the palace (the one with the pipe).

I am creating a set of armor that is colored teal with some spring green accents, and I bought 3 spring dyes from him over the past few trips I've made to town. However, now it seems that he no longer stocks the spring dye.

Is this temporary? Will it come back?

As a corollary, what is the determining factor for when merchants cycle their goods? Every time I come to town? Once an hour? Once every set of small bosses I defeat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen, dye stocks are randomly chosen from a list of dyes available depending on your difficulty, and each merchant chooses their stock at the time of starting the game. If you can't find Spring on any of the vendors who sell dye, just back out to the menu and restart your game and one of them should have it.

Comment: And, if that doesn't work, restart the game again... and again, and again, as needed, until it shows up.