# Who sells Lovely Dye?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find specific dye colors?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67321/where-can-i-find-specific-dye-colors)

I'd rather not pay the inflated Auction House price, but I can't find anyone who sells it in-game. If the seller dye stock is random, who is most likely to sell it, and in what difficulty? Where can I buy Lovely Dye (pink)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lovely Dye seems to be sold randomly by Talnin the Collector in Act 2 on Hell difficulty (nearly every time I check his "Miscellaneuous" tab he sells it). The price is 2160 gold, the  auction house price is ~1400 Gold, so you're better off buying it in the auction house.

Answer (score 1):

The only place I have ever found it was in Hell in the Caldeum Bazaar, the vendor in the top left sells it. I am not sure if it is randomly generated or not.

Answer (score 0):

Act 2 , not in the camp , but inside the actual city