# Did how to find dyes change in RoS (or on console in general)?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

There's a question on where and how to find dyes on [already on the site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67321/where-can-i-find-specific-dye-colors?rq=1), but the answers don't seem to help me at all.

I'm specifically looking for the dyes related to Challenges - Mariner's and Lovely Dye.  However, I'd also really like to be able to find Infernal, Abyssal, Purity, and Elegant Dyes as well.  None of these have ever appeared for me, with any merchant, on any difficulty (I've tried Normal, Hard, and Expert, and am trying Master now.  Will try Torment soon.)

Comment: The difficulties referred to in the linked question have just been renamed on the console (no idea why). There is no "Easy" on the original PC version, but "Hard" = "Nightmare", "Expert" = "Hell", and "Master" = "Inferno".

Comment: @Ben so it is a console thing, thank you.  Still, I can't find any of what I've taken to calling the "rare" or "pure" dyes.  I can find all the off-colors;  teal and scarlet and a pinkish-purple, but I can't find the real blue or red or purple dyes at all.  I'm up to Master now and in Act V with my main character, although when I play with friends I also check all the merchants in acts I and II.  I've never had a single one of the named dyes show up once.

Comment: This is the case for PC as well since the expansion. I think the dyes are available around the level at which you'd start the old difficulties - 20 for the Nightmare ones, 50 for Hell, and 60+ for Inferno.

Comment: I'm at 54, been on Master a while, checked shop in Act V a few times, still the same dyes I've seen since Act 1.  I can find items that are already the color (I'm wearing Mariner's as my chest armor now, with Aquatic on the accents), but not the dye.  Kind of wish the Mystic could "extract" the dye from an item to reuse if it's one of the rare ones.  I've still never seen ANY pink items / Lovely Dyes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Armor_dye) there are a number of dyes that are only available after certain events. Two dyes no longer exist (Pale Dye and Rogue's Dye), and the Bottled Cloud and Bottled Smoke dyes are exclusive to the collector's edition. It should be noted that the vendor stocks will replenish after 15 minutes.

Below are all of the vendors:

> The [Wandering Tinker](http://www.diablowiki.net/Wandering_Tinker) in the Fields of Misery, Tinker's Hovel.
>   [Adenah the Curio Vendor](http://www.diablowiki.net/Adenah_the_Curio_Vendor), House of Curios in the Fields of Misery.
>   [Rodger the Alchemist](http://www.diablowiki.net/Rodger_the_Alchemist), after The Sacrificial Hermit event outside Wortham in Act I.
>   [Arghus the Collector](http://www.diablowiki.net/Arghus_the_Collector) in New Tristram (beginning in Nightmare).
>   [Tilnan the Collector](http://www.diablowiki.net/Tilnan_the_Collector) in Caldeum in Act II. (Or in the Hidden Camp after accepting The Scouring of Caldeum quest)
>   [Javad the Merchant](http://www.diablowiki.net/Javad_the_Merchant) in the Rotting Cellar
>   [Vidar the Collector](http://www.diablowiki.net/Vidar_the_Collector) in Bastion's Keep Stronghold in Act III, additionally in the Bridge Stores on Rakkis Crossing on occassion.
>   [Vidar the Collector](http://www.diablowiki.net/Vidar_the_Collector) in Bastion's Keep Stronghold in Act IV.
>   [Delilah the Collector](http://www.diablowiki.net/index.php?title=Delilah_the_Collector&action=edit&redlink=1) in The Surviviors' Enclave in Westmarch in Act V.

It should also be noted that Javad and Rodger give a discount after their respective events.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have observed in the PC version, which I assume is the same on console when it comes to finding dyes.

Some of the randomly encountered merchants can sell the rarer dyes. One such merchant spawns in an Abandoned Hovel in the Fields of Misery in Act 1 (northern part of the map). Another one I can think of is a random merchant that may appear before the entrance to the caverns of araenae in act 1 (near the bridge before the entrance).

According to [this gameFAQs post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/930659-diablo-iii/62988757), the difficulty may affect which dyes can be available:

```
Epic Dyes = infernal, purity, golden, etc = 5k each
Rare Dyes = spring, summer, aquatic, etc = 2k each
Uncommon Dyes = cardinal, desert, harvest = 1k each
Common Dyes = tanner, etc = 360 each

Normal/Nightmare vendors have = common + uncommon
Hell vendors have = common + uncommon (wider selection) + rares
Inferno vendors have = few common/uncommon (or none at all) + rares (wider selection) + epics (one to three at a time)
```

So I would try running Master (Inferno) and search for one of the random merchants.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the dye you are looking for is in the hometowns.

There are 4 hometowns total (New Tristram, Hidden Alcove, Keep, Westmarch), each of these has at least 1 or 2 merchants around. Talk to them and check to see if they have the "dyes and potions" tab, and check through their inventory. Hop over to the next town if you didn't find the color you were looking for from those merchants.

Finally, if this didn't work, simply close the game and start a new one, all the merchants will refresh their supplies with a new list and you can check their stores all over again for your color.